# UITableViewCell Subclass in swift not appearing in TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

Alright so I've created a subclass of `UITableViewCell` called `TwoColumnCell`, and all I want is a cell with two `UILabels` in it.

Here is my subclass:

```
import UIKit

class TwoColumnCell: UITableViewCell
{
    var firstNameLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
    var lastNameLabel:UILabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.contentView.addSubview(firstNameLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(lastNameLabel)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        firstNameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20.0, 10, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height))
        lastNameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width/2 + 5, 10, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height))
    }

    override init() { super.init(); }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

    override init(frame: CGRect) { super.init(frame: frame) }


}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.tableView.registerClass(TwoColumnCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TwoColumnCell")
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 2;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        var cellIdendifier: String = "TwoColumnCell"

        var cell:TwoColumnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdendifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TwoColumnCell
        cell.firstNameLabel.text = "Jony"
        cell.lastNameLabel.text = "Ive"

        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

But when I run the application, the table view is empty. It's probably a `CGRect` issue, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you set **Cell Identifier** in Xib(or StoryBoard)?
And set **delegate** of TableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `layoutSubviews` is creating *new* UILabels rather than updating the frames on the existing ones. Just needs some tweaks:

```
override func layoutSubviews()
{
    super.layoutSubviews()

    firstNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 10, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height)
    lastNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width/2 + 5, 10, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height)
}
```